# How to minimize all applications except mine?

Tags: delphi, winapi, shell, minimize

I want to minimize all application that are running in the system, except mine.
How can i do this?

I used this code but it works only on **some** computers:

```
procedure MinAllWnd_ByShell;
VAR IntHwnd: Integer;
begin
 IntHwnd:= FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
 PostMessage(IntHwnd, WM_COMMAND, 419, 0);
end;
```

then

```
procedure TFrmMain.btnMinimizeAll_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 { Send MINIMIZE message }
 MinAllWnd_ByShell;                                                            { This sends a message to Windows. Windows sends the minimize signal back to us after a delay }
 Delay(150);                                                                   { We wait few miliseconds to receive the message in our message queue }
 Application.ProcessMessages;                                                  { By now we should have received the message so we process the queue. }

 { Now self restore }
 BringToFront;
 ShowWindow(frmMain.Handle, SW_RESTORE);
end;
```

.

---

Delphi XE/Win XP/Win 7

Comment: 419 feels a bit undocumented...

Comment: What if you delay BringToFront even more, say Delay(1500) ?

Comment: If you don't have complete control over what gets installed on that system, you can't reliably do this nor should you. This bares close resemblance to [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx)

Comment: Same with "&Show the Desktop"? (i.e. 407)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not saying this is a good idea, but you could try to replace the `419` with a simulated Win+M:

```
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(ord('M'), 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```